# The "-e" option does not exist

Tags: laravel

With the following command:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\facade> php artisan make:controller TestController -resource`
I get an error:

> The "-e" option does not exist.

Comment: it needs double "-" here is correct one `php artisan make:controller TestController --resource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because it needs double dashes.

You have:

```
php artisan make:controller TestController -resource
```

Which needs to be:

```
php artisan make:controller TestController --resource
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:controller --resource TestController
```

OR

```
php artisan make:controller TestController --resource
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since geertjanknapen already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.